# How to convert an integer into 24 hours format in JAVA?

Tags: java

I don't know how to convert an integer into 24 hours format in JAVA.

For example:

```
public class Activity 
{
   private Subject subject;
   private int start;
   private int duration;
   private String room;
   private int capacity;
   private int enrolled;


public Activity(Subject subject, int start, int duration, String room, int capacity)
{
    this.subject = subject;
    this.start = start;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.room = room;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return subject.getNumber() + " " + start + " " + duration + "hrs" + " " + enrolled + "/" + capacity;
}
}
```

In the toString() method, I want to convert the int varaible start into format as HH:00. The start variable are integers from 0 - 18. 
I tried to add a method like this:

```
public String formatted(int n)
{
    int H1 = n / 10;
    int H2 = n % 10;
    return H1 + H2 + ":00";
}
```

then pass the variable start to this method. But it doesn't work. I don't understand where goes wrong.

I need some help on this, please!

PS: the result should look like " 48024 18:00 1hrs 0/200 ", I get all other variables correctly formatted except the start variable.

Comment: If you this is a Java 8 question, I recommend you to use [TemporalAccessor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) for your start time and [TemporalAmount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAmount.html) for your duration. For date formatting you have [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: And there's also a java `Duration` class.

Comment: Also possible `return "" + H1 + H2 + ":00";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method fails because your code is equivalent to:

```
return (H1 + H2) + ":00";
```

So it sums up each digit before appending the String!

You can "correct" (or actually hack) it by doing:

```
return H1 + (H2 + ":00");
```

Or even better, use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
public String formatted(int n) {
    // print "n" with 2 digits and append ":00"
    return String.format("%02d:00", n);  
}
```

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Obivously! Corrected :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert into a string in your addition or it will just add the numbers

```
   public String formatted(int n)
    {
        int H1 = n / 10;
        int H2 = n % 10;
        return H1 + "" + H2 + ":00";
    }
```

Comment: Oh...that's why!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
public String formatted(int n)
{
    String hours = "";
    if(n < 10)
    {
        hours = "0" + n;
    }
    else
    {
        hours = "" + n;
    }
    return hours + ":00";
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why the method I write is wrong? I don't understand? It looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: `return "" + H1 + H2 + ":00";` would do.

Java just processes this line from left to right.
So if it first encounters two integers, it will add them up.

However, if you start out by putting a `String` (even though it's empty), the behavior will be corrected.

There are other more readable alternatives as well:

```
return String.valueOf(H1) + H2 + ":00";
```

There are also many utility classes that can help you [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and  [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) could be interesting. But in your case keep it simple. :)